# Deserialize xml into a Linq to SQL object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, xml-serialization

I need to read in XML data posted from external systems, which will be formatted roughly as follows:

```
<Applicant>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  <Address>12 Main St</Address>
</Applicant>
```

This is a direct mapping of my Linq to SQL Applicant class, excluding a few properties.

What's the best way to deserialize xml into a Linq to SQL object, so I can then insert directly into my database?  I'd also like to validate the incoming XML and handle specific errors if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a direct map, you should just be able to use it directly, as long as the types as public and have public parameterless constructors, and the properties (including lists) are get/set.

If you need to tweak the names there is an `XmlSerializer` constructor that allows you to specify all the attributes. This is ideal for your scenario, but you **must** cache and re-use the serializer if you use this constructor overload, otherwise you will leak memory (the dynamic assemblies are not collected).

Here's a full example that removes one property (`XmlIgnore`), changes another to an attribute, and leaves a third as an element.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static readonly XmlSerializer serializer;
    static Program()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides or = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        or.Add(typeof(Foo), "A", new XmlAttributes { // change to an attrib
            XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("tweaked")
        });
        or.Add(typeof(Foo), "B", new XmlAttributes {
            XmlIgnore = true // turn this one off
        });
        // leave C as a default named element
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo), or);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { A = 123, B = "def", C = 456 }, clone;
        string xml;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(sw, foo);
            xml = sw.ToString();
        }
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml)) {
            clone = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(clone.A);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.B);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.C);
    }
}
```

Note also that if you only need to change things at the *type* level (such as `[XmlInclude]`) then you can do this via the `partial class` that LINQ-to-SQL generates; for example:

```
namespace My.Dal.Namespace {
    // add a type attribute to SomeEntity
    [XmlInclude(typeof(SomeDerivedEntity))]
    partial class SomeEntity { } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, he says it's a direct map, _excluding a few properties_.

Comment: @John In which case it *isn't* a direct map, and it can be done by using the overloaded constructor

Comment: @Marc: so that constructor allows you to force in an XmlIgnore? I did not know that. An example would be good.

Comment: @Marc, you're _way_ too fast!

Comment: Great response Marc (as always) - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To validate, you need a XML schema for these XML files coming in - you can fairly easily create one using the `xsd.exe` tool in your Windows SDK directory which takes a XML file and turns it into a xsd (XML schema) file.

If you already have a class that basically matches this XML, yes, the easiest would probably be to just deserialize it into an `Applicant` class:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Applicant));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(.....); // depends on where you get your XML from
Applicant result = (Applicant)ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

That should fill up your `Applicant` object with those properties coming from the XML - this will work as long as you don't leave any required properties empty (and don't have a means to provide a valid default value), and if you don't have any type mismatches in your mappings (e.g. trying to deserialize a string into an INT property or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

It's much more simpler.

First use a DataContractSerializer to Serialize your LinqToXml Entities. 
This returns a byte array. 
With Encoding.UTF8.GetString(the byte array from DataContractSerializer) you get a xml representation of your entities...

Hope it helps